# Pika basic_publish error when publishing large message

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

Pika publish message success whose size less than 10k bytes, and it failed when the size is larger than 10k bytes.

Error information as below:

```
Error. Connection closed, and the message was never delivered.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_mq.py", line 28, in <module>
    ret = test_mq.publish(test_str)
  File "rbmq.py", line 146, in publish
    ret = self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.exc, routing_key=self.rkey, body=body, properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2, ))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 521, in basic_publish
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1106, in _rpc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 218, in process_data_events
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Code as below:

```
    def publish(self, body):
        ret = False
        try:
            ret = self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.exc, routing_key=self.rkey, body=body, properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2, ))
        except pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as exc:
            print('Error. Connection closed, and the message was never delivered.')
            self._reconnect()
            ret = self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.exc, routing_key=self.rkey, body=body, properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2, ))
            print("Try again ret: ", ret)
        except Exception as e:
            print ("PikaMQ publish really error ", e)            
        return ret

test_str_fail = 49143 * 'a' 
test_str_ok = 9143 * 'a'
ret = test_mq.publish(test_str_ok)   #publish success
ret = test_mq.publish(test_str_fail) #publish fail
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you upgrade to pika 0.9.14. The latest version fixed a couple of pretty major socket bugs; including the one causing your issue.

You can upgrade to 0.9.14 using pip:

`pip install pika --upgrade`

This is taken from the not yet finished [changelog](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for 0.9.14.

```
Major issue with socket buffer refactor in 0.9.13 (#328) fixes by cooper6581 and Erik Andersson
```

As an alternative, if for some reason you cannot upgrade from 0.9.13 to 0.9.14 you could try out some of the alternative RabbitMQ clients for Python.

- [AMQP-Storm](https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm) -- [Examples](https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm/tree/master/examples) --   `pip install amqp-storm`
- [Rabbitpy](https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy) -- [Examples](https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy/tree/master/examples) --     `pip install rabbitpy`
- [Py-AMQP](https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq) --      `pip install amqp`
- [Librabbitmq](https://github.com/celery/py-amqp) --  `pip install librabbitmq`
- [txAMQP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txAMQP) -- `pip install txamqp`

*-- A more comprehensive list of alternatives to pika is available on the official RabbitMQ website [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#python-dev).*

Comment: Thanks for the list with viable alternatives. I'd like to add [txAMPQ](https://launchpad.net/txamqp) to it.

Comment: Sure, it wasn't really intended to be a comprehensive list though. I mostly wanted to provide him with a few alternatives similar to pika in case he couldn't get it to work.